# XPath division operator

Tags: xml, xpath

Is the forward slash `/` a valid division operator in XPath expressions?  On page 132 of the book `Pro PHP XML and Web Services` (ISBN-13: 9781590596333), in Table 4-3 (XPath Operators), only `div` is listed as a division operator, but on page 146, there is an example that uses `/` in order to get the rounded average price of numbers in certain elements: `round(sum(//*[local-name()="price"]) / count(//*[local-name()="price]))`

In the example, it seems that the **`/`** immediately before `count` is being used as a division operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've found a mistake.

`/` separates location steps in an XPath; it is never a division operator.

[`div`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-numeric-divide) is the general number division operator, and [`idiv`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-numeric-integer-divide) (in XPath 2.0+) is an integer division operator.